# Rank users by different periods and overall

Tags: mysql, window-functions, mysql-8.0, rank

I'm trying to create a ranking system for a game which should have 2 different rankings. Below you will find the **Model** (or the result after querying the database) which should be presented to the player:

**1. Hot leaderboard** (periods: Day, Week, Month)

```
   - #rank (user's position in the leaderboard)
   - user_fk
   - won games count
   - lost games count
```

**2. General leaderboard** (Overall data)

```
   - #rank (user's position in the leaderboard)
   - user_fk
   - won games count
   - lost games count
```

As you can see, the models are the same, but the queries are different. Below you can find the database structure for the `User` model and for the `Score` logging.

**User model**

- id
- created_at/updated_at
- picture
- nickname
- zone_id
- xp
- played games

  - James: win/lost count
  - Lisa: win/lost count
  - Jacob: win/lost count

As you can see, the user can play against 3 different opponent players: James, Lisa and Jacob. Every time the player finishes a game with an opponent player (CPU), the win or lost counts are incremented. Based on that, a new XP (experience point) is added or subtracted from the user's XP.

**Score log model**

- uuid
- user_id
- date_created
- against
- won (true, false)
- zone_id

For the hot leaderboard I'm trying to write the following query:

```
Select users ordered by number of won games DESC, lost games ASC,
where date_created <= 24h AND againts = OpponentPlayer AND zone_id = ZONE LIMIT 250
```

And for the General leaderboard:

```
Select users ordered by XP DESC, won games DESC, lost games ASC
where updated_at <= 90 days and zone_ID LIMIT 999
```

The third thing that I don't know how to solve is to: **How to get a specific user's rank based on the general leaderboard?**

---

1. Is this the right approach to log user's played games?
2. Should I create a different table for leaderboards and update their value once in a while?

Comment: Do you have MySQL 8.0 or MariaDB 10.2?

Comment: I am using MySQL 8.0 version.

Comment: Study the "windowing functions", such as `RANK()` and `DENSE_RANK()` that are available in that version.